# English Dictionary with Syntax Classifications Download

Tags: english, classification, dictionary, ai, categories

I'm looking for an english dictionary with english words' meaning but also with grammar classifications e.g. `Hi (exclamation)`.

Comment: wiktionary?? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3496/1511